# TStringList.loadfromfile not loading special chars

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using Delphi XE to load a txt file into a TStringList. Problem is, all special chars on my file are being loaded corrupted. My code is simple as :

```
sl := tstringlist.create;
sl.loadfromfile('c:\myfile.txt');
```

Here are the contents of 'myfile.txt' :

```
João Pessoa
```

After loaded to stringlist, it becames

```
JoÃ£o Pessoa
```

How can i fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by replacing this line

```
sl.loadfromfile('c:\myfile.txt');
```

by this :

```
sl.loadfromfile('c:\myfile.txt',TEncoding.UTF8);
```

After that all special chars are loaded correctly.

Comment: Yes, if you know that the file uses UTF-8, this is the way to do it.